Micro frontend - Material UI library duplicate imports webpack
I am implementing the microfrontend architecture, My main app and mf1 app uses material ui,
the material ui library are imported multiple times, even after specifying the singleton property.
which is messing up the styles.
multiple material ui imports
webpack config for both apps
Tried removing the shared library, added import param to false.
